# How we can extract Day, Date, Time in Excel which is in the format of following Fri Aug 07, 2020 05:12 UTC?

Tags: excel-formula

```
    Long Date
```

---

### Fri Aug 07, 2020 05:12 UTC

---

### Day      | Date       | Time  |

### Friday   | 07:10:2020 | 05:12 |

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following to put the text string into just a date time format that excel understands:

```
=DATEVALUE(RIGHT(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-4),LEN(A1)-8))
```

The above will not be affected by number of digits for year, day or hour; only that the bit it is using has 4 chars at the front (Fri and space) and 4 at the end (space and UTC).

Since you have two digits for both day and hour, this could be simplified with using MID, like:

```
=DATEVALUE(MID(A1,5,LEN(A1)-8))
```

To extract a date from a text string representing a date, you can use the DATE function e.g. `=DATE([year],[month],[day])`.

To get those parts from a text string you can use `=MID([input text string], [start position], [number of characters])`. So you could do MID for each component (year, month etc) needed, then put the results through the DATE function.

Date formats in Excel are distinguished between what is *stored* and what is *displayed*.

What is *stored* depends on your excel settings.
What is *displayed* depends on your excel settings as well as your "regional and language options" or equivalent settings in your computer's operating system.

To change what is *displayed*, set a custom format (ctrl-1, first tab, last list item) to something like `Ddd Mmm dd, yyyy hh:mm`.

Otherwise regional and language options, and program settings, can override how the date is shown (which can be important if you are sharing workbooks, especially with unknown future users).

Is the input UTC or do you need to convert?

If you need to convert, do you have a fixed offset in hours? If so, it is a simple formula. For example: `=A1+3/24` for UTC-3 hours.

To change what is *stored*, first understand whether the number stored represents the number of days since 1 Jan 1901, or 1 Jan 1904, or some other convention (such as 1 Jan 1970).

Then decide if you want to store it as a date or a text string.

Then decide if you want to store it as 3 copies of the same value (each displaying a different aspect: day, date, time) or if you just want each value to be its own part not the whole date "hidden" and the display set.

To store it as a text string, use `=TEXT(A1,"Dddd")`, `=TEXT(A1,"MM:DD:YYYY")` and `=TEXT(A1,"HH:MM")`.

Watch out for 24 or 12 hour time: the difference is whether "AM/PM" is appended. Your input is likely 24h time but check another example from the dataset to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

to get the date from that string use:

```
=--MID(A1,5,LEN(A1)-8)
```

Put that in three cells.  Then format the cells:

day cell: `dddd`

Date Cell: `dd\:mm\:yyyy`

Time Cell:  `HH:MM`